# Не запускается httpd

Tags: centos, httpd

Перезагружаю`httpd`

```
service httpd restart
```

После получаю вот такое сообщение!

> Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with
>   error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe"
>   for details.

Ввожу команду `systemctl status httpd.service`
Вот что получаю!

```
* httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)                                                                                                                                         
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/httpd.service.d                                                                                                                                                                                      
           `-nofile.conf                                                                                                                                                                                                            
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-06-26 09:20:08 UTC; 1min 34s ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)                                                                                                                                                                                                             
           man:apachectl(8)                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  Process: 2241 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 2239 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2239 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)                                                                                                                                                                                     

Jun 26 09:20:08 server httpd[2239]: [Wed Jun 26 09:20:08.701242 2019] [so:warn] [pid 2239:tid 140257062369408] AH01574: module php7_module is already loaded, skipping                                                              
Jun 26 09:20:08 server httpd[2239]: [Wed Jun 26 09:20:08.701940 2019] [so:warn] [pid 2239:tid 140257062369408] AH01574: module php7_module is already loaded, skipping                                                              
Jun 26 09:20:08 server httpd[2239]: [Wed Jun 26 09:20:08.702328 2019] [so:warn] [pid 2239:tid 140257062369408] AH01574: module php7_module is already loaded, skipping                                                              
Jun 26 09:20:08 server httpd[2239]: AH00534: httpd: Configuration error: More than one MPM loaded.                                                                                                                                  
Jun 26 09:20:08 server systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE                                                                                                                                
Jun 26 09:20:08 server kill[2241]: kill: cannot find process ""                                                                                                                                                                     
Jun 26 09:20:08 server systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1                                                                                                                                      
Jun 26 09:20:08 server systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Jun 26 09:20:08 server systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.                                                                                                                                                         
Jun 26 09:20:08 server systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

Дальше прописываю `httpd -t`

> ```
> [Wed Jun 26 09:22:45.649848 2019] [so:warn] [pid 2289:tid 140211353860224] AH01574: module php7_module is already loaded,skipping                                                              
>
> [Wed Jun 26 09:22:45.649923 2019] [so:warn] [pid 2289:tid 140211353860224] AH01574: module php7_module is already loaded,skipping                                                              
>
> [Wed Jun 26 09:22:45.649974 2019] [so:warn] [pid 2289:tid 140211353860224] AH01574: module php7_module is already loaded,skipping                                                              
>
> AH00534: httpd: Configuration error: More than one MPM loaded.
> ```

Comment: приложите конфиг апача,  а вообще вот документация https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mpm.html

Comment: 1. https://serverfault.com/q/646107/292034 2. приложите к тексту вопроса вывод `$ grep -r mod_mpm /etc/apache*`